# jQuery Fade Images simultaneously

Tags: jquery, image

I am using jQuery to cross fade images.

This is the code I am using:

```
$('.' + currentimage).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.' + selectedimage).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This is fading the first image out 100% before the selected image begins to fade in. Is there a simple way to begin fading in the second image when the first image has faded out by say 60-70%?

EDIT: All good answers. I think there is a further problem. My images are not showing up on top of each other - and only 1 image is visible at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('.' + currentimage).fadeOut('slow');
$('.' + selectedimage).delay(100).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Cleanest way of doing it, despite all current answers working.

Answer (score 3):

`slow` is 600ms so 420 would be 70%

```
$('.' + currentimage).fadeOut('slow');
$('.' + selectedimage).delay(420).fadeIn(600);
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `.delay(420)` instead of `setTimeout()` as it's just cleaner, simpler code.

Comment: But now it's just the same as an earlier answer ;)

Comment: @Archer - It's not the same.  Adam actually figured out the appropriate delay for 70%.  The other answer did not.

Answer (score 1):

You could cheat and apply part of the fade (using [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/), call your other function, and then continue.

```
$('.' + currentimage).fadeTo('slow', .6, function() {
    $('.' + selectedimage).fadeIn('slow');
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: I like this, but wouldn't you `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` at the same time, not `fadeOut` after the `fadeIn` finishes?

Answer (score -1):

That is because the function you are declaring there for `fadeOut()` is a callback function which is to be called only after the `fadeOut()` is complete.  You should simply be able to execute one item right after the other to get the desired effect. This is not as exact as starting at X% on the `fadeOut()`, but you can probably adjust the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` time to get the desired effect or throw in a `delay()` on the `fadeIn`.

```
$('.' + currentimage).fadeOut('slow');
$('.' + selectedimage).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: The problem with this is the first image is fading to black, and then the other image only appears when the first image has finished fading out.